# Método de encontrar raízes de uma função no Fortran

Tags: fortran, do-while

Eu criei um código que usa 3 métodos para determinar as raízes de uma função, o método direto de chutar valores de x, o de Newton-Raphson e o das secantes. No método direto, eu defini valores de x próximos das raízes, e eu usei do while para adicionar incrementos de 0.1 a estes valores até o momento em que a função mudasse de sinal, situação de proximidade de f(x) = 0. Só que como resultado, meu programa fica inifitamente dentro desses do while e não roda o resto. Aqui está meu código

```
  program raizes
     implicit none
     integer n, i           !escolha dos chutes iniciais para cada raiz
     real*8, parameter :: r1=-3.d0/10.d0,r2=1.d0/10.d0,r3=4.d0/10.d0
     real*8 r1d, r2d, r3d, xd !novos valore de x a serem testados no
                               !método direto
     real*8 r1_nr, r2_nr, r3_nr, nr1, nr2, nr3 !variáveis do método 
                                               !Newton-Raphson
     real*8 r1_si,r2_si,r3_si,r1_s,r2_s,r3_s,sec1,sec2,sec3 !variáveis do
                                        !método das secantes
     read(*,*)n
     open(10,file="tab3_out.dat")
     xd = 0.d0
     do i = 0, n-1
     !Método Iteração direta
        xd =xd + 1.d0/10.d0 !incremento do chute inicial do método direto
        do while (f(r1d).ge.0.d0) !situação em que a função quase muda 
                                  !de sinal
           r1d = r1 - xd !como a raíz está em -0.5, o r1 deve ser 
                         !diminuído
        end do
        do while (f(r2d).ge.0.d0)
           r2d = r2 + xd !como a raíz está em 0.33,o r2 deve ser   
                       !aumentado        
        end do
        do while (f(r3d).le.0.d0)!situação em que a função está quase 
                                 !mudando de sinal
           r3d = r3 + xd !como a raíz está em 0.66, o r3 deve ser 
                         !aumentado
        end do
     !Método Newton-Raphson (N-R)
        r1_nr = r1 !----------valores iniciais de x
        r2_nr = r2
        r3_nr = r3
        nr1 = r1_nr - f(r1_nr)/df(r1_nr) !equação de N-R
        nr2 = r2_nr - f(r2_nr)/df(r2_nr) !equação de N-R
         nr3 = r3_nr +f(r3_nr)/df(r3_nr) !equação de N-R
        r1_nr = nr1 !alterando os valores iniciais de x para a 
        r2_nr = nr2 !próxima iteração
        r3_nr = nr3
     !Método Secante
        r1_si = -2.d0/10.d0 !valores xi-1 na equação do método da secante
        r2_si =  0.d0
        r3_si =  3.d0/10.d0
        r1_s = r1           !valores xi na equação
        r2_s = r2
        r3_s = r3
        sec1 = r1_s - f(r1_s)*(r1_s - r1_si)/(f(r1_s)-f(r1_si)) !fórmula
                                                    !método das secantes
        sec2 = r2_s - f(r2_s)*(r2_s - r2_si)/(f(r2_s)-f(r2_si))
        sec3 = r3_s - f(r3_s)*(r3_s - r3_si)/(f(r3_s)-f(r3_si))
        r1_si = r1_s  !alterando os valores de xi-1 e xi para a próxima 
                       !iteração
        r2_si = r2_s
        r3_si = r3_s
        r1_s = sec1
        r2_s = sec2
        r3_s = sec3
        write(10,*) i,r1d,r2d,r3d,nr1,nr2,nr3,sec1,sec2,sec3
     end do
     close(10)

     contains !----------definições da função e de sua derivada
        real*8 function f(x)
     real*8 x
          f = 18.d0*(x**3.d0)-9.d0*(x**2.d0)-5.d0*x+2.d0
     end function f

     real*8 function df(x)
     real*8 x
          df = 54.d0*(x**2.d0)-18.d0*x-5.d0
     end function df
  end program raizes
```

Eu gostaria de uma sugestão para resolver esse problema dos do while.

Comment: Os valores das variáveis `r1d`, `r2d` e`r3d` não mudam dentro dos respcetivos *loopings* (*while*). Provavelmente, ou os valores das variáveis `r1`, `r2` e `r3` ou o valor de `xd` devem ser atualizados dentro desses *loopings* para que eles terminem.

Comment: Vou tentar fazer com que elas sejam atualizadas, obrigada pela dica.

Answer (score 1):

Eu não consegui resover o problema com do while, então usei só if e else. Ficou assim a parte do método direto.

```
  program direto
     implicit none
     integer n, i
     real*8, parameter :: r1=-3.d0/10.d0,r2=1.d0/10.d0,r3=4.d0/10.d0
     real*8 r1d,r2d,r3d, xd, raiz_1,raiz_3,raiz_2
     read(*,*)n
     !método iteração direta
     xd = 0.d0
     do i = 0, n-1
        xd =xd + 1.d0/5.d0
        if(f(r1d).ge.0.d0)then
           r1d = r1 - xd
        else
           raiz_1 = r1d
        end if
        if (f(r2d).ge.0.d0) then
           r2d = r2 + xd
        else
           raiz_2 = r2d
        end if
        if (f(r3d).ge.0.d0) then
           r3d = r3 + xd
        else
           raiz_3 = r3d
        end if
        write(*,*)i, raiz_1, raiz_2, raiz_3
     end do

     contains
        real*8 function f(x)
        real*8 x
            f = 18.d0*(x**3.d0)-9.d0*(x**2.d0)-5.d0*x+2.d0
     end function f
  end program direto
```

Answer (score 1):

Acho que você precisa inicializar os valores de `r1d`, `r2d` e `r3d` antes de usá-los na primeira chamada de `f(r1d)`. Se você não fizer isso, os valores iniciais dessas variáveis serão atribuídos pelo sistema, ou seja, você não tem como predizer nem ter controle. Assim, sua função pode se comportar de maneira inesperada.
Se você inicializa-las com 0.0, ou com os valores de `r1`, `r2` e `r3`, creio que resolva o problema na primeira versão do código (sem os if/else).